# Get custom attribute from python ldap query

Tags: python, list, dictionary, ldap, tuples

i succesfully retrive objects that i need from a Python ldap query, the result is like this

```
[('uid=xxxxxx,ou=People,dc=xxxxxxx,dc=eu', {'departmentcode': ['xxxxx']})], [('uid=xxxxxx,ou=People,dc=xxxxxxx,dc=eu', {'departmentcode': ['xxxxx']})]
```

But from this result, i need just departmentcode. So, How to acess departmentcode value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
data = [('uid=xxxxxx,ou=People,dc=xxxxxxx,dc=eu', {'departmentcode': ['xxxxx']})], [('uid=xxxxxx,ou=People,dc=xxxxxxx,dc=eu', {'departmentcode': ['xxxxx']})]
departmentcode = []
for elem in data:
    departmentcode.append(elem[0][1]['departmentcode'])
```